# supabase in Next JS returning an empty array when data is in relevant tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

It seems I am always returning an empty array when trying to pull data from my tables. This is how I am doing it, after following the docs and several tutorials.

```js
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  async function getTableData() {
    let { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints')
      .select('*');

    setTableData(data);
    console.log(tableData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTableData();
  }, []);
```

I have data in the table as so.

[image]

The only thing I can think of is the naming of the table??

I have also tried the following

```js
let { data: SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints, error } = await supabase
  .from('SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints')
  .select('*')
```

But getting an error `ReferenceError: data is not defined` and in VSC I'm getting `All destructured elements are unused.ts(6198)` with the above.

I have always seen tutorials just use `data` though.

Comment: don't destructure the response, store it in variable and console log it and see the params.

Comment: if you read the supabase docs this is how they do it. They destructure all their calls

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had to turn off RLS on my tables.

Answer (score 6):

Open your supabase project dashboard. Then go to the "Authentication" menu on the side left.
Then open "Configuration" -> "Policies".

[image]

Then create **"New Policy"** for your table.

And put `true` inside the **"USING expression"** column.

Please see my screenshot below;
[image]

It will give you an authorization to access the **Public** table that using RLS.
RLS is important to used, because on production it make your table cannot edit by anyone. And you can set the **"Allowed Operation"** (see the second screenshot) only for `SELECT`.

So, It doesn't matter if the **anon key** is scattered. That was only can see the content but cannot change it up.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting back no records even with RLS turned off. Turns out NextJS was caching the response.

Hard-refreshing (using `cmd-shift-r` or holding down the refresh button in Chrome) worked for me.

Comment: wow, thanks. This was giving me a headache for an hour now.

Answer (score 2):

you should disable RLS (not secure) or define policy for your table . (every table in your project has its own policies and should create ruls seprately)